# How to count the sum of the value in 1 column and with the same value of another column?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm going to count the sum of the value in rmNum column and with the same value of rmType.

[image: table of reserve]

From the table as shown in image above, can someone please teach how to to sum up the value of rmNum by referring to the same "keyword" of rmType?
i am new to PHP and i still get confusing about this even i went through the teaching part in other websites and questions that asked in Stackoverflow.

Edit 2:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $conn->error;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $typeRow = $row;
    }
    $sql1 = "SELECT rmType, SUM(rmNum) as total FROM room GROUP BY rmType";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row1['rmType'] . ' had ' . $row1['total'] . ' room reservations';
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

this is the coding i used after all, it still give me `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean`

Comment: i hope someone can teach me with clearer way as i still don't understand after searching on other websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT rmType, SUM(rmNum) as total FROM table GROUP BY rmType";
```

where `table` is the name of the table. This will return a table with two columns: the `rmType` and the total sum of `rmNum` for that type.

You can then process it like:

```
$sql = "SELECT rmType, SUM(rmNum) as total FROM table GROUP BY rmType";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['rmType'] . ' had ' . $row['total'] . ' room reservations';
}
```

**EDIT**: In case you want the total sum, you do not need to group, you can simply use:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(rmNum) as total FROM table";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo 'The total number of reservation rooms is ' . $row['total'];
}
```

Comment: Group by mean it will be group automatically or should i write like ...GROUP BY rmType="sbed";  ?

Comment: @PhpLearner: it will automatically group by `rmType`. So for your case, a table will emerge that maps `tSBed` on 1, `dBed` on 1, and `fBed` on 3.

Comment: I hope you can help me to work out on it..i will mark this as answer as well.

Comment: may i ask how to called the total sum out please?

Comment: @PhpLearner: you mean all types together?

Comment: nope...total sum of each rmType..because i need to count the number until it reach the max

Comment: @PhpLearner: well that's what the first query is all about (see part above the edit).

Comment: I edited the part...it still giving the error..may you help me figure it out?

Comment: same error giving even assoc or array...can you please contact me through other way like facebook? or any way for me to contact you? that would be more easier..thanks
https://web.facebook.com/zhong.yong.7?_rdc=1&_rdr

Comment: problem solved bro..i using the wrong table...haha..well...YOU TOO GREAT !